# Component accepts Component as an argument-React

Tags: reactjs

The scenario is like I want to create a component which can accept component as an argument or props.
So created one functional component named as scenarioComponent.js with props

```
function ScenarioComponent(props) {
  return <div> <h1>{props.Title}</h1> 
         <div className='row'>
         {props.HTMLCode}//this will be the another component HTML tag
         </div>
         <div className='row'>
         {props.REACTCode}//this will be the another component REACT code
         </div>
         </div>;
}
```

Once this component is ready we can call this to pass the necessary props:
below code in SampleComponet.js where i want to use scenario component.

```
function SampleComponet(props) {
import ScenarioComponent from './components/ScenarioComponent';

return ( <div>
<ScenarioComponent Title="My New component" HTMLCode={<div>My Heading<div>} REACTCode={import ScenarioComponent from '.components/ScenarioComponent';}>
</div>
);
}
```

I have tried above line of code and referred the [text](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) .
Able to achieve partially but want to make it more flexible like we should pass complex component.So any help will appreciated.

Comment: send a JSX or HTMLElement for your HTMLCode, REACTCode props. e.g) `<ScenarioComponent HTMLCode={<div>hello</div>} REACTCode={<SomeComponent />} />`

Comment: Thank you for reply it would be more helpful if you can elaborate it with sample if possible

Comment: Yes., I do agree with you @Jyoung., You have to pass the JSX elements (like <div>hello</div>) and not (import ScenarioComponent from '.components/ScenarioComponent'). Because inside ScenarioComponent you are directly using `props.HTMLCode`.

Comment: Still, if you want to follow your approach, change it like below

function ScenarioComponent(props) {
  return <div> <h1>{props.Title}</h1> 
         <div className='row'>
         <props.HTMLCode /> // --> Change 1 
         </div>
         <div className='row'>
         <props.REACTCode/> // --> Change 2

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel thank you for the reply.I am importing bcoz i want to use it in another componet.Let me edit the question.So that it will more clear.

Comment: @Anushweta., I saw the edited question. Still, you are passing the HTMLCode prop as JSX element and REACTCode prop as React Component. Pass both of them as JSX elements or Pass both of them as React Components.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented before,

```
// e.g) in your src/components/ComponentA.jsx
export default function ComponentA() {
  return <div>hello</div>;
}

// e.g) in your src/components/ScenarioComponent.jsx
export default function ScenarioComponent(props) {
  return (
      <div>
        <h1>{props.Title}</h1> 
        <div className='row'>
         {props.HTMLCode}//this will be the another component HTML tag
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
         {props.REACTCode}//this will be the another component REACT code
        </div>
      </div>);
}

// in your src/app.jsx or src/pages/app.jsx

import ComponentA from 'src/components/ComponentA'

function App() {
  return <ScenarioComponent 
           title="this is title"
           HTMLCode={<div>hello</div>} // send HTMLElement
           REACTCode={<ComponentA />} // send JSX
         />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. The problem is you can't put an `import` inside a prop. Instead, just do the `import` at the top of your file:

```
import ScenarioComponent from '.components/ScenarioComponent';
```

Then pass the component as a prop:

```
... REACTCode={<ScenarioComponent/>} ...
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of @Jyoung answer, if you still want to pass the elements as props, you can do like the below.

```
function ComponentA () {
  return <div>hello</div>;
}

function ScenarioComponent(props) {
  return (
      <div>
        <h1>{props.Title}</h1> 
        <div className='row'>
         <props.HTMLCode />//this will be the another component HTML tag
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
         <props.REACTCode />//this will be the another component REACT code
        </div>
      </div>);
}

function App() {
  return <ScenarioComponent 
           title="this is title"
           HTMLCode={HTMLComponent} // send Component
           REACTCode={ComponentA} // send Component
         />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another one :**
Instead of passing components as props you wrap them with your `ScenarioComponent` component so you recieve them as `props.children`:

```js
<ScenarioComponent>
  <ComponentA key="c1" />
  <div key="c2">
    <table>
    /....
    </table>
  </div>
</ScenarioComponent>
```

```
const ScenarioComponent = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="row">{children.find((ch) => ch.key === "c1")}</div>
      <div className="row">{children.find((ch) => ch.key === "c2")}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```